# Normal derivative on boundary

Tags: derivatives, vectors

Given
\begin{equation}
u_m(x)= \frac{8}{R^3}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_1 x_1}{R}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_2 x_2}{R}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_3 x_3}{R}
\end{equation}

with the boundary $\delta\Omega = \{x\mid x_1=R, 0<x_2<R, 0<x_3<R\} $
and $m$ is a vector with $m=(m_1,m_2,m_3),m_i∈ \mathbb{N}$

The author then calculates the normale derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial n} u_m(x)$ on the boundary $\delta\Omega$ and derives

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial n} u_m(x) = \frac{8 \pi m_1}{R^4}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_2 x_2}{R}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_3 x_3}{R}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

I'm very new to the topic of normal derivatives and I've never seen it calculated on "strange" boundaries like $\delta \Omega$. Could someone briefly describe how we can derive (1)?

Comment: Can you tell what is given about $m_1$? Is it an integer?

Comment: Yes, it is an integer. So $m$ is a vector with $m=(m_1,m_2,m_3), m_i \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: OK you may want to edit and add that to the question for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \displaystyle u_m(x)= \frac{8}{R^3}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_1 x_1}{R}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_2 x_2}{R}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_3 x_3}{R}$

$ \displaystyle \nabla u_m(x)= \bigg(\frac{8 \pi m_1}{R^4}\:\cos\frac{\pi m_1 x_1}{R}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_2 x_2}{R}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_3 x_3}{R}, \frac{\partial u_m(x)}{\partial x_2}, \frac{\partial u_m(x)}{\partial x_3}\bigg)$

The given boundary is $\delta\Omega = \{x\mid x_1=R, 0<x_2<R, 0<x_3<R\}$

As you can see the boundary is a square in plane $x_1 = R$ and the unit normal vector to this plane is either $(1, 0, 0)$ or $(-1, 0, 0)$.

Please note that,

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial u_m(x)}{\partial n} = \hat{n} \cdot \nabla u_m(x) = \pm \frac{8 \pi m_1}{R^4}\:\cos \pi m_1\:\sin\frac{\pi m_2 x_2}{R}\:\sin\frac{\pi m_3 x_3}{R} \ $  (as $x_1 = R$)

Given $m_1 \in \mathbb{N}, \cos \pi m_1 = \pm1$